# How to integrate/call teradata db in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am fairly new to ApacheCamel and I am trying to integrate a TeraData DB call to our database and I cannot figure out the below error message. In addition, I am running this in fuse.

> 2016-01-22 16:17:36,725 [Blueprint Extender: 1] ERROR org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl - Unable to start blueprint container for bundle fuse-maria-bundle
>   org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to find property descriptor URL on class com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver

What I have done so far is added the below in my `blueprint.xml`

```
<bean id="teradata" class="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:teradata://[inser database connection]"  />
        <property name="user" value="myuser" />
        <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
    </bean>
```

I have this in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>15.10.00.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>tdgssconfig</artifactId>
    <version>15.10.00.14</version>
</dependency>
```

...and followed the instruction from this [link](https://forums.teradata.com/forum/general/pom-file-for-maven-project) where I downloaded the driver from `teradata.com`.

In my route, I have the below code.

```
 @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://testtimer?period=1000000")
                .enrich("sql:select count(*) from  table1?dataSource=#teradata")
                .log("Processing ${body}");


    }
```

Any ideas would help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Missing link added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- You have to download database drivers (`terajdbc4.jar`). I think, you
  already have it...
- Now you have to install drivers to your container (**Karaf**, because you wrote "Fuse").

Installing from file, windows example (if drivers not OSGi ready), **Karaf** console:

```
install -s wrap:file:///c:/install/terajdbc4.jar
```

or installing from **Maven** repository:

```
install -s wrap:mvn:com.teradata.jdbc/terajdbc4/15.10.00.14
```

Mission complete.

About converting jars:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/DeployJar-Wrap.html

UPDATED:

The problem is that class `com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver` has no properties url, URL, and so on...

I recomend you to try `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:teradata://[inser database connection]" />
    <property name="username" value="myuser" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
</bean>
```

Second option is `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ncr.teradata.TeraDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:teradata://[inser database connection]" />
    <property name="username" value="myuser" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Alexey - I did the install in my machine and ran this code.  mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.teradata.jdbc -DartifactId=terajdbc4 -Dversion=15.10.00.14 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/Users/me/Downloads/Tera/terajdbc4.jar >> it seems to me it is the same with your command mine is just mac version. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Your command install drivers into Maven repository. Now you have to install it from Maven repository (or from file) into your container, Fuse. My commands is not for Mac, commands is for Karaf(Fuse) console (OSGi server, the server running your Apache Camel and many other bundles). How you run your example?

Comment: Hi Alexey - I installed the terajdbc4.jar and config in karaf by using this command : osgi:install 'wrap:file:///tmp/terajdbc4.jar. For some reason when I tried using "install" It is throwing me an error of error executing command. After doing that, it still gives me same exact error.

Comment: I am running my code from intellij and doing maven package command.

Answer (score 0):

The error is specific to the property URL you set on the TeraDriver bean , doesnt look like that property is avaialble on the class , can you try using "url" in small case